# django-cms picture plugin - bulk upload

Tags: django, django-cms

What would be the best way to make it possible to upload many pictures at once to some cms page? or alternatively, how can I change the admin  template/view to make it work? 
is there a nice way to achieve it?

(I'm working withe the default picture plugin)

Comment: why don't you use gallery plugin? where you can add many images at once.

Comment: @CrazyGeek tnx, Ill check it, but nevertheless it could be nice to do it with the build-in picture plugin

Comment: Ok, than you can add a text plugin in that plugin create a normal html table, So click on each row and add sub plugin i.e. picture plugin. This will help you as you want.

Comment: it still requires me to add each plugin one by one, I would like to select many images from my computer and upload them. I know of course how to make this functionality, but don't know how to integrate it with the cms

Comment: I think picture plugin does not support multiple uploads So in that case you need to use normal html5's file input with multiple upload option enable and handle all uploads programmatically in JS.

Comment: ok tnx, Im using the gallery you suggested and it works great so thanks for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

picture plugin does not support multiple uploads. why don't you use gallery plugin? where you can add many images at once.